# Is there any working Apache module to implement NTLM on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, apache-2.4, ntlm

I am trying to configure NTLM authentication for an internal site running on Apache/Ubuntu Jammy. I was able to implement LDAP authentication. Still, I want to make the login/auth process smooth as the user is already logged into his work computer using their domain credentials.

I tried installing the Apache module via apt based on some older documentation I found via Google, but the packages are no longer available.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-auth-ntlm  
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-auth-ntlm
```

Could you please suggest how I can implement NTLM authentication for my Apache proxy server, which is running on Debian-based Linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2):

Since 2010, [Microsoft no longer recommends NTLM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nlmp/1e846608-4c5f-41f4-8454-1b91af8a755b?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in applications.

> NTLM does not support any recent cryptographic methods, such as AES or SHA-256. It uses [cyclic redundancy check (CRC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nlmp/780943e9-42e6-4dbe-aa87-1dce828ba82a#gt_9cb45a36-92bb-4c14-b2fd-2ad7e2979bfd) or message digest algorithms ([[RFC1321]](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=90275)) for integrity, and it uses RC4 for encryption. Deriving a [key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nlmp/780943e9-42e6-4dbe-aa87-1dce828ba82a#gt_718bfd46-3cd2-45e8-befa-55f5c9f3be7b) from a password is as specified in [[RFC1320]](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=90274) and [[FIPS46-2]](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=89871). Therefore, applications are generally advised not to use NTLM.[<81>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nlmp/a211d894-21bc-4b8b-86ba-b83d0c167b00#Appendix_A_81)

Microsoft Kerberos authentication should be used instead.

Although [`libapache2-mod-auth-kerb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libapache2-mod-auth-kerb) exists for Jammy, it has already been [removed from Debian 11](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=libapache2-mod-auth-kerb). Therefore, I would use [`libapache2-mod-auth-gssapi`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libapache2-mod-auth-gssapi) instead for future implementations.

1. `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-auth-gssapi`
2. Configure Apache, e.g.,

   ```
   <Location /private>
       AuthType GSSAPI
       AuthName "GSSAPI Single Sign On Login"
       GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/httpd.keytab
       Require valid-user
   </Location>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @esa-jokinen . 
Is there any step-by-step guide that I can follow to implement this? I am very new to this implementation and want to understand how to configure the keytab file and what it actually contains. 
(Also, do I need to coordinate with the Active Directory team to provision anything to me so my Ubuntu server can work for this integration?)